# Django many to one reverse query on the same field

Tags: sql, django, postgresql, sqlite

I have a one to many relationship between two tables ...

**Item** - id, title

**ItemAttribute** - id, item_id, attribute_code(string, indexed)

where attribute_code can have values for colors, sizes, qualities, dimensions, etc,
- like codes for 'Blue', 'Black', 'White', 'S', 'L', 'XL', '250g', '400g', etc

**Question**: How do I query for all **Items** that are either ('Blue' OR 'White') AND 'XL'

I prefer using Django's ORM, but if someone could even help out with raw SQL it would do just fine. Thanks.

Comment: I assume `item` is a `ForeingKey` from `ItemAttribute` to `Item`?

Comment: Yes. Item is a ForeignKey in the ItemAttribute model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This subquery:

```
select item_id
from item_attribute
group by item_id
having sum(attribute_code in ('Blue', 'White')) > 0 and sum(attribute_code = 'XL') > 0
```

returns all the `item_id`s that you want.
So you can join it to the table `item`:

```
select i.*
from item i inner join (
  select item_id
  from item_attribute
  group by item_id
  having sum(attribute_code in ('Blue', 'White')) > 0 and sum(attribute_code = 'XL') > 0
) a on a.item_id = i.id
```

or use the operator `IN`:

```
select *
from item 
where id in (
  select item_id
  from item_attribute
  group by item_id
  having sum(attribute_code in ('Blue', 'White')) > 0 and sum(attribute_code = 'XL') > 0
)
```

If you have really large data sets you could also try `EXISTS`:

```
select i.*
from item i
where 
  exists (select 1 from item_attribute where item_id = i.id and attribute_code in ('Blue', 'White'))
  and
  exists (select 1 from item_attribute where item_id = i.id and attribute_code = 'XL')
```

Comment: Yes, it uses standard SQL. The top 2 queries need a little modification in sum()

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: Since there could be several EXISTS clauses in my query, will performance improve if I create an [attribute_code + item_id] index instead of only indexing the attribute_code? Will it help the db in ANDing the subqueries?

Comment: `item_id` should also be indexed, not just `attribute_code` and yes a composite index might help. There are also cases where the order of the columns in the definition of the composite index matters. So try both (item_id, attribute_code) and (attribute_code, item_id). This is for speeding up each subquery. As for the ANDs unfortunately there is no guarantee that a short circuit evaluation will be performed.

Comment: Yes, `item_id` is indexed since all ForeignKeys are indexed by default in Django. I wanted to know your opinion on ANDs as my sample set as of now is yet small. Thank you once again :)

Comment: For sure EXISTS performs really fast because it returns as soon as it finds what it is searching for and does not have to scan the full data set. So a composite index will speed it up. But for *several* EXISTS I can't say if the whole query will perform better than conditional aggregation with a join.